# Архивация через zip списка папок по-отдельности

Tags: linux, unix, zip

Есть список папок:

```
2014-12-17
2014-12-21
2014-12-22
2014-12-23
2015-01-13
2015-01-14
2015-01-15
2015-01-16
2015-01-17
```

Как заархивировать папки, названия которых начинаются с "2014" с созданием одного архива, либо, с созданием множества архивов, названия которых совпадают с названием папок?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запаковать папки, начинающиеся с номера года в архив с именем номера этого года:

```
#!/bin/bash
for year in {2012..2016}
do
    zip -r $year $year-* >/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

На выходе - 2012.zip 2013.zip и т.д.

Comment: что на выходе будет? я не силён в скриптах. спасибо

Comment: а как без вывода добавляемых файлов в консоль? их в каждой папке по 5 тысяч по 150 кб каждый

Comment: @mee, об этом написано в man-е к этой программе (можете выполнить команду `$ man zip` и почитать). опция называется (как и у многих других программ) `-q`.

Comment: А как каждую папку в свой архив?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for y in {2016}
do
    for m in {1}
    do
        for d in {1..9}
        do
            zip -r $y-$m-$d $y-0$m-0$d >/dev/null 2>&1
        done

        for d in {10..31}
        do
            zip -r $y-$m-$d $y-0$m-$d >/dev/null 2>&1
        done
    done
done
```

Сохранил и назвал файл scr.sh
Как теперь его запустить?

Comment: Добавьте ему права на исполнение chmod +x scr.sh, а запуск ./scr.sh если из той же со скриптом директории, либо через полный путь к нему

Comment: ничего не происходит после команды ./scr.sh

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `ls -1`; do zip $i.zip $i; done
```

Comment: `echo \`$i\`` — что, по-вашему, здесь должно произойти? из зачем нужна конструкция `\`ls -1\``, если достаточно лишь `*`? и где точка с запятой межу `for` и `do`? вероятно, вы и не пробовали запускать то, что предлагаете.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я исправил синтаксическую ошибку, протестировал.
для echo `$i` предполагалось, что будет выведено название каталога, перед архивированием, но на практике выяснилось, что zip умеет отображать вывод того, что было добавлено в архив. выглядит это следующим образом:
`#   adding: 2014-12-22/ (stored 0%)`